# Value of type 'UserControlform' cannot be converted to 'Form' in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls, bunifu

I have an error in 'UserControl` form

namely in `BunifuSnackbar` but if I use it in the form there is no error.

the error is `Value of type 'PgStockin' cannot be converted to 'Form'`

Please guide Me.

Thanks

```
Partial Public Class PgStockin
        Inherits UserControl  

`The error is below this line of code, namely in the word `Me`
BunifuSnackbar2.Show(Me, "Please delete item detail first ", Bunifu.UI.WinForms.BunifuSnackbar.MessageTypes.Error, 5000, "",
               Bunifu.UI.WinForms.BunifuSnackbar.Positions.MiddleCenter, Bunifu.UI.WinForms.BunifuSnackbar.Hosts.FormOwner)

End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

A form and a user control are two different things. Clearly, that `Show` method is expecting a form and you are passing it a user control. If you want to show a form, you need to create a form, not a user control.

A user control is basically a container to which you can add other controls and then reuse them as a group. You design it in the same way as you would a form but you then use it in the same way you would any other control. It has to be added to a form or another child control on a form, just like any other control, not shown independently as you would a form.

So, the question is why you created a user control in the first place. Do you want to show it independently or do you want to add it to a form? If the answer is that you want to do both then you cannot do the former directly. You'd have to add your user control to a form and then show the form.